# Minimizing effects of large number of files

Tags: filesystem, backup, rsync, tar

I need to manage a filesystem with a large number of files (hundreds of thousands).

This filesystem is `rsync`ed periodically. The vast majority of files don't change often, but since there's so many, rsync takes a long time, because it has to `stat` all of them.

In an effort to reduce the time `rsync` takes, I've been `tar`ing big directories that aren't changed, but this leads to usability problems. Every time a user needs a file inside of the archives, they must open the archive and extract the file.

Is there a way to make `rsync` faster on such a scenario, with the change being transparent (or at least not annoying) to the non-technical user?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing around with the `rsync` options? The options `-c`, `-W` and `--delay-updates` could be helpful.

Comment: For information, I found that by using the -c (checksum) option, the transfer took longer to complete than it did without it.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try.